# How to add xpra repository list?

Tags: xpra

On this page, https://xpra.org/trac/wiki/Download, you see a list of repository list for xpra.

But what commands do I need to run it? Confused. Completely new to linux and ubuntu.

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: For what OS/release?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you proceed it should be noted that `xpra` package is already included in official Ubuntu repositories (in the *universe* pocket). So you can simply get version 2.1.3 on your Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with simple commands like:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get install xpra
```

If you really need to add their repository - proceed with the following commands:

```
# add GPG key
wget -q https://xpra.org/gpg.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
# add XPRA repository
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://xpra.org/ bionic main"
# install XPRA package
sudo apt-get install xpra
```

and you will get the latest version from [xpra.org](http://xpra.org).

Comment: The issue was that the page metnions adding the "universe" repo, but there is no instruction, so ppl new to Ubuntu and linux are completely lost on how to proceed.

Comment: Don't use the version from the Ubuntu repositories, it is buggy and dangerous: https://xpra.org/trac/wiki/Packaging/DistributionPackages

Comment: Thanks! BTW, I've changed the second command to: `wget -q https://xpra.org/repos/focal/xpra.list -O- | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xpra.list`

Comment: TIL add-apt-repository  command thank you